# R ggplot resize plot area window

Tags: r, resize, plot, ggplot2, area

I have problems resizing the plot area. If you look at the following example you will see that the label of the x-axis "x" is out of the range of the plot window/area and therefore not visible any longer. I tried to resize the plot window/area with

```
dev.new(width=10, height=10)
```

but that does not increase the space of the white boundary outside the actual plot area. I also saved the plot as PDF hoping that the label "x" will reappear in the PDF but that's also not the case.

Is it somehow possible to increase that particular area?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10) 
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -5))
```

Comment: Does `dev.new(width=5, height=5)` fix it?

Comment: no it does not. It just increases the entire plot area but not the space/margin of the area outside the actual plotting area where the x and y labels of the axes are placed

Comment: Ah ha, I misunderstood. Isn't it because of `vjust = -5`? What if you replace that with `vjust = -0.5`?

Comment: yeah that of course would work but I created this example on purpose to demonstrate my problem. I want to have bigger fonts and slightly more far away from the axes itself. But with my font size and my vjust  my labels are half gone...

Comment: `opts(plot.margin = unit(c(2, 2, 2, 2), "cm"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the size of the plotting area available for axis labels and text, you can use

```
opts(plot.margin = unit(c(2, 2, 2, 2), "cm"))
```

to specify the margin size of each side of the plot.