# ggplot2 is cutting out the plot's margins

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a density in `base R` and then in `ggplot2`.

When I use `base R` the plot comes out alright, but in `ggplot2` the margins are cut out.

This is the plot in `base R`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mvtnorm)
library(reshape2)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'reshape2'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     smiths

sd <- 1 / 2
# sigma
s1 <- sd^2

mu1 <- c(0, 0)
sigma1 <- matrix(c(s1^2, 0, 0, s1^2), nrow = 2)

# first two vectors
x.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
y.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)

# the third vector is a density
z <- matrix(0, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
z[] <- dmvnorm(expand.grid(x.points, y.points), mean = mu1, sigma = sigma1)

contour(x.points, y.points, z, xlim = range(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3), nlevels = 5, drawlabels = TRUE)
```

[image]

And this is the plot in `ggplot2`:

```r
df <- reshape2::melt(z)
df <- transform(
  df,
  x = x.points[Var1],
  y = y.points[Var2]
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value)) +
    xlim(-3,3) +
    ylim(-3,3) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

When I started working on the plots, both plots were coming out well. I was running `par(pty = "s")` (unfortunately if I include the `par` command in the `reprex()`, something goes wrong and there is no plot.) The `par` command was working and giving me a square plot for both `base R` and `ggplot2`. Then I added a line and some points to the `ggplot2` plot:

```r
points <- data.frame(
  x = c(0, 1, 1.5, 1, 0),
  y = c(-3, -2.5, 0, 2.5, 3)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value)) +
    xlim(-3,3) +
    ylim(-3,3) +
    geom_path(mapping = aes(x=points[,1], y=points[,2]), points) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x=points[,1], y=points[,2]), points) +
    theme_classic()
```

After I added the points, the `ggplot2` plot started cutting out the margins.

I have tried adding `dev.new(width=10, height=10)` following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109610/r-ggplot-resize-plot-area-window), but of course, it just opens a new graphing design and, in addition, the margins are also cut. I have also tried to reset the graphing device with `dev.off()`, and restarting the R session.

Comment: Just as a general comment; ggplot2 doesn't respond to base R `par`  or `mfrow` function.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the classic theme `theme_classic()`: it looks like that no matter the type of plot, `theme_classic()` is going to draw only two sides of the box around the plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(mvtnorm)
library(reshape2)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'reshape2'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     smiths

sd <- 1 / 2
# sigma
s1 <- sd^2

mu1 <- c(0, 0)
sigma1 <- matrix(c(s1^2, 0, 0, s1^2), nrow = 2)

# first two vectors
x.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
y.points <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)

# the third vector is a density
z <- matrix(0, nrow = 100, ncol = 100)
z[] <- dmvnorm(expand.grid(x.points, y.points), mean = mu1, sigma = sigma1)

df <- reshape2::melt(z)
df <- transform(
  df,
  x = x.points[Var1],
  y = y.points[Var2]
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value)) +
    xlim(-3,3) +
    ylim(-3,3) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>